# MVC routemap not working as expected in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jobs page where there are multiple parameters like jobType,  workload, etc. The page may or may not have any/all of the parameters.

Routemap :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "JobsRoute",
        url: "Jobs/Index/{workload}/{jobType}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", action = "Index", workload = UrlParameter.Optional, jobType = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "PostJob", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Controller (partial method code) :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string workload = "", string jobType = "")
    {
        SearchJobs model = new SearchJobs();
        
        using (var context = new OutsourceEntityContext())
        {
            model.lstJobs = context.Jobs.ToList();
            if (!workload.Equals(""))
            {
                int jobWorkloadKey = context.JobWorkload.Where(t => t.Name.Equals(workload)).First().Key;
                model.lstJobs = model.lstJobs.Where(t => t.WorkloadKey == jobWorkloadKey).ToList();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I want such URLs to work :

```
http://localhost:51576/Jobs/workload/15-20%20hours%20per%20week
http://localhost:51576/Jobs/workload/15-20%20hours%20per%20week/jobType/Hourly
```

Comment: You route has `/Jobs/Index/{workload}/{jobType}` - if you don't want `Index` in it, then change it to  `/Jobs/{workload}/{jobType}` but its unclear what you expect your 2nd example to hit - that's a completely different route

Comment: the second should also hit the same page with second parameter having some value .. ( not empty )

Comment: In the second one you have 4 route values (your definition has only 2). And only the last parameter can be option if your using routes. In not clear what your trying to do

Comment: workload and jobType are the actual parameters which may or may not have any values ..

e.g. workload can have value like "15-20 hours per week ", " More than 40 hours per week ", "Less than 10 hours per week" , etc.

jobType has values like "Hourly","Fixed"...

Please note both these parameters may or may not have a value ... it is optional ...

Comment: Read my last comment again. _only the last parameter can be optional if your using routes_

Answer (score 0):

Since you need jobtype and workload in the url, you should specify that when you define the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Jobs",
    url: "Jobs/workload/{workload}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Job", action = "Index", 
                                                        workload = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "JobsWithJobType",
    url: "Jobs/workload/{workload}/jobtype/{jobType}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Job", action = "Index",
                                                         jobType = UrlParameter.Optional}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Or If you want to do the attribute routing way,**

Enable attribute routing in `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{            
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //default route definition goes here
}
```

and decorate your action method with attribute routes.

```
public class JobsController : Controller
{
    [Route("jobs/workload/{workload}/jobtype/{jobtype?}")]
    [Route("jobs/workload/{workload?}")]
    [Route("jobs")]
    public ActionResult Index(string workload = "", string jobType = "")
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```